# Simple disconnnected graph with 4 components

Tags: graph-theory

Draw a simple disconnected graph, $G$, with $10$ vertices and $4$ components, and also calculate the maximum number of edges possible in $G$?

I have this question and I couldn't find the answer. Can someone offer helpful suggestions?.

Comment: This isn't a site for "finding answers", it's for helping you solve your own problems. Can you draw one graph that meets those requirements? Then draw a few more. Then try to find the maximum number of edges possible. Edit the question to tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Maximum number of edges can be obtained when graphs are complete graphs. So the question becomes: With $10$ vertices and $4$ components, how can we seperate the vertices so that complete graphs, say $K_a, K_b, K_c, K_d$, have maximum number of edges *in total*? How many edges does complete graph $K_n$ have?